# winbind Could not connect to dssetup pipe: NT_STATUS_RPC_INTERFACE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba

I am trying to add a new member server running Ubuntu  to a Samba Active Directory domain. On first glance everything seems to work, but when querying the status of the winbind service with `service winbind status`, I'm getting the following messages (most of it in red, so it's probably an error even though there are several messages in green saying "ready"):

```
● winbind.service - Samba Winbind Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-04-21 15:47:43 UTC; 17h ago
   Docs: man:winbindd(8)
         man:samba(7)
         man:smb.conf(5)
Main PID: 1728 (winbindd)
 Status: "winbindd: ready to serve connections..."
  Tasks: 5 (limit: 76899)
 Memory: 27.0M
 CGroup: /system.slice/winbind.service
         ├─1728 /usr/sbin/winbindd --foreground --no-process-group
         ├─1738 winbindd: domain child [MYSERVER]
         ├─1739 winbindd: domain child [MYDOMAIN_AD]
         ├─1754 winbindd: idmap child
         └─5023 winbindd: domain child [BUILTIN]

Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1728]: [2022/04/21 15:47:43.857695,  0] ../../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3203(initialize_winbindd_cache)
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1728]:   initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1728]: [2022/04/21 15:47:43.861490,  0] ../../lib/util/become_daemon.c:135(daemon_ready)
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1728]:   daemon_ready: daemon 'winbindd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com systemd[1]: Started Samba Winbind Daemon.
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1738]: [2022/04/21 15:47:43.864574,  0] ../../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cm.c:1873(wb_open_internal_pipe)
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1738]:   open_internal_pipe: Could not connect to dssetup pipe: NT_STATUS_RPC_INTERFACE_NOT_FOUND
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1738]: [2022/04/21 15:47:43.867483,  0] ../../source3/rpc_server/rpc_ncacn_np.c:454(rpcint_dispatch)
Apr 21 15:47:43 myserver.ad.mydomain.com winbindd[1738]:   rpcint_dispatch: DCE/RPC fault in call lsarpc:2E - DCERPC_NCA_S_OP_RNG_ERROR
```

`uname --all` output:

```
 Linux myserver 5.4.0-109-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`winbindd --version` output:

```
 Version 4.13.17-Ubuntu
```

The AD Primary and Secondary domain controllers are up and running. All computers are running Unbuntu Linux 20.04 and all packages are up to date. There is no Windows server involved or even in the network.

I have no idea what causes this and how I can fix it. Google didn't turn up anything useful either. Any hints? Are there any other logs where I could look for more information?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a noisy error message nothing else.

https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/commit/5fe7536145dc2c29ec71f6077188d74f4e08abd6